# Java - set the field value to the correct type from string(reflection)

Tags: java, reflection

I have class like this:

```
public enum  Type {
    ONE, TWO
}

@Data
public class Car {
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private Type type;
}
```

I have new object:

```
Car car = new Car();
```

And I have this data:

```
Map<String, String> data....

name - BMW
year - 2018
type - TWO
```

**key and value - String**

And I need set this values to object(except for reflection, I see no ways)

```
    Field year = car.getClass().getDeclaredField("year");
    year.setAccessible(true);
    year.set(car, data.get("year"));//2018 as string
```

I get exception(differently and could not be I know):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.example.mapper.Car.year to java.lang.String
```

**Therefore, the question is**  - how do I correctly cast the value to the desired type to set in the field?

This is a simple example, because the real task is very long explained. If in short - I get a list of values (they are always a string) and the names of the fields in which they change (also a string) and must update the fields of the object with new values

Comment: In your simple example, you have to cast the `year` to an `int`, using `Integer.valueOf()`. In a more complex example, i would write a mapper that maps a `String` to the corresponding type (the type can be read via reflection). Those mappers could be placed in a type map.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but simply avoids it: `new ObjectMapper().convertValue(data, Car.class)` (Use Jackson's json-based conversion from one type to another. There are alternatives, of course)

Answer (score 3):

A valid solution with minimum effort would be using a JSON library as a workaround, since they have already implemented value instantiation from strings for the most common types.

For example, using ObjectMapper:

```java
   Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
   data.put("year","2018");
   data.put("name", "BMW");
   data.put("type", "TWO");
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   Car car = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(data), Car.class);
```

Comment: Excellent answer for those who'd like to convert URI parameters into POJO object. Just an additional note: if you need not to worry for case sensitivity; you can just consider using:

**mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);**

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is indeed the way to go. You can get the type using [`field.getType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()) and then check for concrete classes using [`Class.isAssignableFrom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)):

```
final Class<?> type = field.getType();
if (int.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
    typedValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
} else if (type.isEnum()) {
    typedValue = Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) type, value);
} else {
    // Assume String
    typedValue = value;
}
```

Of course this can become almost arbitrarily complex, but here's a fully working sample for your provided values. That should give you a gist on how to proceed:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class CarFiller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("name", "BMW");
        data.put("year", "2018");
        data.put("type", "TWO");

        Car car = new Car();
        fillField(car, "name", data);
        fillField(car, "year", data);
        fillField(car, "type", data);

        System.out.println(car);
    }

    private static void fillField(Object instance, String fieldName, Map<String, String> data) throws Exception {
        Field field = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);

        String value = data.get(fieldName);
        Object typedValue = null;
        final Class<?> type = field.getType();
        if (int.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            typedValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
        } else if (type.isEnum()) {
            typedValue = Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) type, value);
        } else {
            // Assume String
            typedValue = value;
        }

        field.set(instance, typedValue);
    }

    enum  Type {
        ONE, TWO
    }

    static class Car {
        private String name;
        private int year;
        private Type type;

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setYear(int year) {
            this.year = year;
        }
        public void setType(Type type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Car [name=" + name + ", year=" + year + ", type=" + type + "]";
        }       
    }
}
```

(See also [on ideone](https://ideone.com/5zVnZP))

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend not to use reflection everywhere it's possible. Like in your exact example.

You can create an enum class wich contains BiConsumers for each of your fields in Car class:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

@Data
public class Car {
    private String name;
    private int year;
    private Ttc.Type type;

    static enum CarEnum {
        name((car, value) -> car.setName(value)),
        year((car, value) -> car.setYear(Integer.parseInt(value))),
        type((car, value) -> car.setType(Ttc.Type.valueOf(value)));
        private BiConsumer<Car, String> setValueConsumer;

        CarEnum(BiConsumer<Car, String> setValueConsumer) {
            this.setValueConsumer = setValueConsumer;
        }

        static Car createCar(Map<String, String> data) {
            Car car = new Car();
            data.forEach((key, value) -> valueOf(key).setValueConsumer.accept(car, value));
            return car;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it in the next way:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", "BMW");
data.put("year", "2018");
data.put("type", "TWO");
Car.CarEnum.createCar(data);
```

Answer (score -2):

Java is statically typed. Therefore you need to provide the correct type yourself. [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) takes a String and returns an Integer.

```
int year = Integer.valueOf("2018");
```

Converting a String to an Enum works the same.

```
Type  type = Type.valueOf("ONE");
```

[`Enum.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) is called in the background.

Of course you also need to add some error checking.

---

I'd recommand avoiding the use of reflection in such a case. You could use a different approach, e.g.

```
  class Car
  {
    private final Type type;
    private final String name;
    private final int year;

    private Car(Builder builder)
    {
      this.type = builder.type;
      this.name = builder.name;
      this.year = builder.year;
    }

    static class Builder
    {
      private Type type;
      private String name;
      private int year;

      public Builder setType(String type)
      {
        this.type = Type.valueOf(type);
        return this;
      }

      public Builder setName(String name)
      {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
      }

      public Builder setYear(String year)
      {
        this.year = Integer.valueOf(year);
        return this;
      }

      public Car build()
      {
        return new Car(this);
      }

    }

  }
```

You could also add a `setData` method to the builder

```
      public Builder setData(Map<String, String> data)
      {
        this.year = Integer.valueOf(data.get("year"));
        this.type = Type.valueOf(data.get("type"));
        // etc.
        return this;
      }
```

Then create a car with `Car c = new Car.Builder().setData(data).build();`.